# Ubuntu OS security

Tags: installation, preinstallation

My friend suggest me Ubuntu OS instead of windows 7 because on ubunut no virus,trojan,rootkit this is true ?

Thanks,
Michi

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42284/what-is-the-ubuntu-built-in-virus-protection  Oh and security is more a USER issue. A one char password is easy to remember but no amount of security will stop someone from messing up a system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Mostly yes:

Firstly, the way linux handles ownership of files, programs run by the user do not automatically have permission to alter system files, and that is what a virus tends to want to do. This makes it intrinsically much more safe than Windows even when people do write malware to attack it. It is often said that as so many less people are on linux there are almost no viruses (etc) written for it, whether this is because of the shear difficulty of writing the viruses, or because of the lack of effort is (arguably) not the point. The reality is there is almost no malware.

Secondly, any security problems which are detected in linux are patched quickly and update automatically, no need for lots of extra (often expensive or annoying) protection software. So it is a lot safer, but the idea that there is absolutely no malware is not strictly true.

Comment: "Firstly, as so many less people are on linux there are almost no viruses (etc) written for it." These 2 have no correlation. The person that manages to create an active virus on linux and get it to spread as it can on Windows will be hailed as a god by his kinsmen. That is a reason independent of the amount of Linux users.

Answer (score 1):

Viruses exist for all platforms, but they tend to affect the Windows world more because:

- There are simply more Windows machines available to attack.
- The Linux security model (user-level security) used in Ubuntu is VASTLY superior to that of Windows.

Basically, using Ubuntu (Linux) puts you more ahead in the game than a Windows user (ex: not allowing you to log-in to the GUI as root by default), but it can't save you from bad habits or bad system administration.  Don't log-in as root, don't run a web browser as root or via sudo, and don't download software that you don't trust.  Good habits go a long way, and Ubuntu makes it easier to employ good habits.

This question [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed) does a great job of detailing this subject.