# Are there any spyware threats due to 3rd party plugins?

Tags: ppa, viruses, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

I installed the plugin mentioned in the following link and after that, by Ubuntu 12.04 LTS behaves a little strange, particularly keyboard shortcuts are not working as expected.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/recoll-lens-full-text-search-unity-lens.html

Actually my worry is not about keyboard shortcuts, but are there any spyware threats by installing 3rd party applications (not through Ubuntu software centre) like that.

Comment: Using third party PPA's has its own risk , as said by the Ubuntu official team.For security clarifications you can refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28069/how-is-the-system-kept-secure) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42284/what-is-the-ubuntu-built-in-virus-protection).